# Matlab : Insert values from a 2-d matrix into a 3-d matrix on some condition

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

output is a 3d matrix with `size(output) == [height width N]` and input is a 2d matrix with `size(input) == [height width]` . I need to implement the following code in one line.

```
for k = 1:size(output,3)
    f = output(:,:,k);
    i_zero = (f==0);
    f(is_zero) = input(is_zero);
    output(:,:,k) = f;
end
```

Comment: I would suggest using a variable name other than `input` as it matches the built-in command with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , anyway its a code snippet and I am not using it in the actual code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers solve the problem when there is a exact comparison to 0 (as OP required) but for the sake of generalization if you intend to change for another comparison be aware that not all methods work in the same way.
Example below:

CODE:

```
%Simulation
output=rand(10,10,3);
input=rand(10,10);
% output=randi(9,10,10,3);
% input=randi(9,10,10);

%OP code
output2=[]
for k = 1:size(output,3)
    f = output(:,:,k);
    i_zero = (f<0.5);
    f(i_zero) = input(i_zero);
    output2(:,:,k) = f;
end

%repmat code
output3=output;
new_input=repmat(input,1,1,size(output,3));
output3(output<0.5)=new_input(output<0.5);
any(output2(:)-output3(:))

%bsxfun code
output4 = bsxfun(@times,output<0.5,input) + output;
any(output2(:)-output4(:))

%other variation code
output5 = (output<0.5).*input(:,:,ones(1,size(output,3)))+ output;
any(output2(:)-output5(:))

% bultin code
output6=output;
output6(output<0.5)=builtin('_paren',repmat(input,[1,1,size(output,3)]),output<0.5);
any(output2(:)-output6(:))

'-----'
any(abs(output2(:)-output3(:))>eps)
any(abs(output2(:)-output4(:))>eps)
any(abs(output2(:)-output5(:))>eps)
any(abs(output2(:)-output6(:))>eps)

'-----'
sum(abs(output2(:)-output3(:)))
sum(abs(output2(:)-output4(:)))
sum(abs(output2(:)-output5(:)))
sum(abs(output2(:)-output6(:)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
ans =

     0


ans =

     1


ans =

     1


ans =

     0


-----


ans =

     0


ans =

     1


ans =

     1


ans =

     0


-----


ans =

     0


ans =

  150.5088


ans =

  150.5088


ans =

     0
```

Comment: That's probably floating point errors on any that manipulated the data as opposed to directly copying to the new location, try `any((output2(:)-outputn(:))>tol)`, with some tolerance eg `tol=eps`

Comment: I would suggest using this - `output = randi(9,height,width,N)-1
input = randi(9,height,width)` to avoid floating point issues.

Comment: no its not. @RTL that code is not correct you need abs

Comment: @Divakar that gives wrong results for the same methods

Comment: sorry my derp... Divakars method relies on the fact your replacing zeros... the new value is added the the old value, its broken by the comparison >0.5 instead of ==0

Comment: yep. that should be it

Comment: Nice observation , But I do not need to worry as I know the values of output I need to replace are actually zero not close to zero .:)

Comment: @Nishant I think accepting ASantosRibeiro's other solution would make more sense as this one talks about a very different (from the original problem) case.

Comment: @Divakar Well I thought,Others may be viewing this problem not for exact comparison, In that case This answer will be really helpful, If they would want an exact comparison still this answer would work fine.

Comment: @Nishant As I said before as well that this solution is based on a very different problem from the one mentioned in the question. The problem talked about in this problem could be further optimized if brought to the notice of others. Also, this is only a benchmarking solution, copying codes from other solutions and giving us the benchmarking results and thus not providing any new solution. I highly recommend ASantosRibeiro's other solution to be accepted rather.

Comment: @Divakar I believe this is not benchmarking , It doesn't talks about performance issues , but it talks about which approach is correct and which is wrong, I believed all of them to be correct , but some came out to be wrong, and this fact must be visible to others viewing this question. Regarding that this is not answer to my question, I believe that this is a general answer which is better, Any other person can change just the `<` sign to `==` sign to get the specific answer to this question.

Comment: @Nishant I won't call it "wrong", for example my solution came out different/"wrong" when compared to the other solutions with this "general error-checking solution". My solution was specific to the original post and uses the specificity in it. Questions could be asked on how do you define "general", which to me is a comparative term. Someone can include 4D or 5D or even higher case and call it a "general" case or someone else could use a vector instead of the scalar used in the original post, instead for comparison. Hope you get my point really.

Comment: @I get your point. But I am not sure about the other way round. My only concern is any person viewing this question should be well aware of the facts mentioned in this answer as well as the answer to this question and, this answer provides both of these.

Answer (score 5):

`bsxfun` approach -

```
output = bsxfun(@times,output==0,input) + output
```

Alternative approach -

```
output = (output==0).*input(:,:,ones(1,N))+ output
```

Comment: I was waiting for this one. :)

Comment: Isn't this part obsolete: `.*(output~=0)` ?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Damn, silly me, of course, you are right! Edited, Thank you!!

Comment: @Divakar I knew there would be an answer using `bsxfun` by you , It seems you cannot let go of `bsxfun`

Comment: @Nishant Sorry can't help it really :)

Comment: I under thought this... much more sensible approach... +1 of course

Comment: The `input(:,:,ones(1,N))` part is very clever. Easier to write than a `repmat`,  and probably faster

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks again! I must be looking to benchmark these two approaches, but I think `bsxfun` would come out as the better choice.

Answer (score 3):

I hope the "I need to implement" is not a homework.

Here goes a solution that should solve your problem although not in one line.

```
new_input=repmat(input,1,1,size(output,3));
output(output==0)=new_input(output==0);
```

Comment: Thanks , worked like a charm , And I assure you its not a homework , I am just in a hurry

Answer (score 1):

Here is in a one liner... but uses the undocumented `builtin('_paren',...` to subscript reference to the output of a function

```
output(output==0)=builtin('_paren',repmat(input,[1,1,N]),output==0)
```

without the the undocumented `builtin` this method gets messy if you want it in one line...

```
output=subsasgn(output,struct('type','()','subs',{{output==0}}),...
    subsref(repmat(input,[1,1,N]),struct('type','()','subs',{{output==0}})))
```

...sadly I forgot using masks and adding two matrices together was an option...

Comment: yep. that’s a generalization of what I proposed. nice to see though as I am still not too familiar with the builtin function

Comment: Though this is just one line instead of 2, I would actually prefer the two lines as given by @ASantosRibeiro.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I agree I would almost always do this is more than one line its much more legible, (the only time i've actually seriously used the `builtin('_paren',...` is creating anonymous functions)

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on a single line solution, you can use the `(:)` operator along with the `mod` command:

```
output(output(:)==0) = input(mod(find(output(:)==0)-1,height*width)+1)
```

where the `-1` and `+1` are in order to avoid index `0`

Answer (score -3):

You should have the 'cat' function:
http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/cat.html
`cat(3,matrix1,matrix2,...)` to concatenate along the 3rd dimension.

Comment: what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: I am trying to avoid loops so do you have a method to implement the above without loops

Comment: Then, does it have to be in one line or without loops?

Comment: already provided a solution in the answer below... What I said is that cat does not solve in any way the code presented. it only concatenates matrices.

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro `cat` will solve the problem using loops by `new_input = []; for k = 1:size(ouput,3) new_input = cat(3,new_input,input); end` . But I need a solution without loops. Thanks for your solution

Comment: @Nishant That use of `cat` would just be a strange way of using `repmat`.

Comment: @Nishant and still that does not do the same as your code in the question. You can just make a dummy example and subtract both results

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro it is doing the same as `repmat` is doing . I don't see the difference